# SAM run without rebuild

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

I have started to use AWS SAM for python. When testing my functions locally I run:

```
sam build --use-container
sam local start-api 
You can now browse to the above endpoints to invoke your functions. You do **not** need to restart/reload SAM CLI while working on your functions, changes will be reflected instantly/automatically.
sam local invoke ...
```

Then, if I make changes to the code it is not reflected without rebuilding when I invoke my function again. Is there any trick that I am missing here? This prompt is not clear to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to update your file directly under .aws-sam/build folder to see your changes without rebuilding.

Comment: This is not useful and it is not a good practice.

Comment: haha.  I totally forgot I used to do this. +1

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/920 & https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/901,  you are expected to have two consoles/terminals open.  One where you run `sam local start-api` and leave it alone.  And another where you run `sam build` repeatedly (whenever you need to update).

If you find this > slightly annoying,

- see https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/901#issuecomment-650629408
- upvote https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/921

Answer (score 0):

If you have npm and nodemon installed globally, you can create a MakeFile in your app root and add the following commands. Then in two separate terminals, run `make build-sam` and `make start-sam`. This will run the build command and watch changes to your app, and run the sam build command everytime you save changes (You can also run the commands directly in the terminal without a Makefile). Then the api will automatically pick up the changes in the second terminal (Note that I am working in python, but you can use this for any language, just alter the nodemon command with your language)

```
build-sam:
    nodemon --watch './**/*.py' --signal SIGTERM --exec 'sam' build -e "py"
start-sam:
    sam local start-api
```